# Save/Edit button issues using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a day planner for class (see image below) and I'm having difficulty adding an edit/save button. What I would like is for it to initially read "edit" and once its clicked, the user should be able to edit the middle rows (which currently read "write"). I would like to use jQuery.

So far this is working for only the first row, and I can't figure out how to make it work for the rest of the rows as well. I would also like that once the user clicks the edit button, the column that the user will be editing is bordered. Can anyone assist?
[image]

This is how my HTML is styled. I cant fit all of it but there are 8 rows, listed alphabetically (a-i, named col-a1,col-a2,col-a3, col-b1, col-b2, col-b3 and so on)

```
 <div class = "container">
        <div class = "row my-row">
            <div class = "col my-col col-a1"> 9am </div>
            <div class = "col my-col col-a2" > </div>
            <div class = "col my-col col-a3"> edit </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "row my-row">
            <div class = "col my-col col-b1"> 10am </div>
            <div class = "col my-col col-b2">  </div>
            <div class = "col my-col col-b3"> edit </div>
```

And here is my JQuery:

```
$(function(){
$(document).on('click','.my-row .col-a3' , function(){
    let editable = $(this).prev('.col-a2').attr('contenteditable');
    if(editable){
        $(this).text('edit');
        $(this).prev('.col-a2').removeAttr('contenteditable');
    
     }
      else{
        $(this).text('save');
        $(this).prev('.col-a2').attr('contenteditable','true');
    }
})
});
```

Comment: `$(document).on('click','.my-row .col-a3'` here your adding click event for only `col-a3`

Comment: Yes I know, I was asking how to include all of them.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
$(document).on('click','.edit_btn' , function(){
    let editable = $(this).prev('.edit_cont').attr('contenteditable');
    if(editable){
        $(this).text('edit');
        $(this).prev('.edit_cont').removeAttr('contenteditable');
        $(this).prev('.edit_cont').removeClass('edit_cont_border');
     }
      else{
        $(this).text('save');
        $(this).prev('.edit_cont').attr('contenteditable','true');
        $(this).prev('.edit_cont').addClass('edit_cont_border');
    }
})
});
```

```css
.edit_cont_border{
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
        <div class = "row my-row">
            <div class = "col my-col col-a1"> 9am </div>
            <div class = "col my-col col-a2 edit_cont" > </div>
            <div class = "col my-col col-a3 edit_btn"> edit </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "row my-row">
            <div class = "col my-col col-b1"> 10am </div>
            <div class = "col my-col col-b2 edit_cont">  </div>
            <div class = "col my-col col-b3 edit_btn"> edit </div>
        </div>
</div>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice! Any idea how I can make it so that the editable column displays a border around it once I click the edit button?

Comment: check my updated answer, and make an answer as accepted.